# Is this Double-Checked Locking that is not Broken?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

This [article](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) explains "Double-Checked Locking" where the idea is to reduce lock contention. As the article explains it does not work. See the code sample in the table "(Still) Broken multithreaded version "Double-Checked Locking" idiom".

Now I think I found a variant that should work. Question is whether that is correct. Let's say we have a consumer and a producer that exchange data through a shared queue:

```
class Producer {
     private Queue queue = ...;
     private AtomicInteger updateCount;

     public void add(Data data) {
         synchronized(updateCount) {
             queue.add(task);
             updateCount.incrementAndGet();
         }
     }
}

class Consumer {
    private AtomicInteger updateCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private int updateCountSnapshot = updateCount.get();

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            // do something
            if(updateCountSnapshot != updateCount.get()) {
                // synchronizing on the same updateCount 
                // instance the Producer has
                synchronized(updateCount) { 
                    Data data = queue.poll()
                    //  mess with data
                    updateCountSnapshot = updateCount.get();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question now is whether you think this approach works. I'm asking to be sure, because tons of things would break if it doesn't ... The idea is to reduce lock contention when only entering a synchronized block in the consumer when the updateCount has changed in the meanwhile.

Comment: Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel. There is a well-known thread-safe structure for communicating between producers and consumers and that is a `BlockingQueue`

Comment: The reason is that the thread running the consumer is also busy doing other things, which it can't do when doing a blocking take. Periodically calling poll() is also not so smart (also poll eats some CPU cycles).

Comment: Then you have an architecture problem not a concurrency problem. There is nothing wrong with periodically calling `poll` - you may be optimizing prematurely.

Comment: What I'm playing with is intended to be some scheduling system similar to Apple's Grand Central Dispatch. So performance will be an issue, but I agree that you have a point concerning premature optimisation. Besides that do you think the algorthm is correct? Thanks for any opinions issues being pointed to.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are looking more for a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

You should consider the following:

- This is not double-checked locking.
- Your consumer will spin on nothing and eat cpu while no data is arriving.
- You use an AtomicInteger as a Semaphore.
- A BlockingQueue will do all of this for you.
- You haven't properly ensured that `updateCount` is shared.
- You do not have to synchronize on atomics.

Here's a simple Producer/Consumer pair for demonstration.

```
public class TwoThreads {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("TwoThreads:Test");
        new TwoThreads().test();
    }

    // The end of the list.
    private static final Integer End = -1;

    static class Producer implements Runnable {

        final Queue<Integer> queue;

        public Producer(Queue<Integer> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    queue.add(i);
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }
                // Finish the queue.
                queue.add(End);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // Just exit.
            }
        }

    }

    static class Consumer implements Runnable {

        final Queue<Integer> queue;

        public Consumer(Queue<Integer> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean ended = false;
            while (!ended) {
                Integer i = queue.poll();
                if (i != null) {
                    ended = i == End;
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        Thread pt = new Thread(new Producer(queue));
        Thread ct = new Thread(new Consumer(queue));
        // Start it all going.
        pt.start();
        ct.start();
        // Wait for it to finish.
        pt.join();
        ct.join();
    }

}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for the effort you took. As a matter of fact it is not difficult for me to develop something like you have worked out above. Nevertheless, thanks for your effort. My post was mostly about performance optimization. Now I did a little measurement and to my surprise AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet takes more time than LinkedTransferQueue.poll! I was very surprised, because I was sure that poll does much work incrementAndGet. So, things are already fine the way they are. No further ado required.

Comment: @ollip - More evil has been done in the name of optimisation than any other practice - Albert Fortran.

Comment: Nice quote :-). Does this Albert Fortran really exist or is it humorous?